# touchesBegan removes press state of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibezierpath, touchesbegan

I am subclassing a UIButton so I can have a button with a custom shape. The shape is specified by points on a UIBezierPath. To disable tapping on an area of the UIButton that the user shouldn't be able to tap. (UIButton is rectangular, but UIBezierPath is Triangular) I added a touchesBegan method to determine if the touch location is inside/outside the UIBezierPath. I am successful in this, but I noticed that I lost the pressed state of my UIButton. Upon implementing touchesBegan, the UIButton no longer changes color when being pressed/highlighted.

**Draw the shape:**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withAngle:(AngleType)angle andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){

        [self setImage:[Utils imageWithColor:color andSize:frame.size] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        _path = [UIBezierPath new];

        self.angleType = angle;

        switch (angle) {
            case AngleLeft:
            {
                [_path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, elementHeight(self))];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(elementWidth(self), elementHeight(self))];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(elementWidth(self), 0)];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(15, 0)];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, elementHeight(self))];
            }
                break;
            case AngleRight:
            {
                [_path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, elementHeight(self))];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(elementWidth(self),elementHeight(self))];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(elementWidth(self) - 15, 0)];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
            }
                break;
            case AngleBoth:
            {
                [_path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(15, 0)];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, elementHeight(self))];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(elementWidth(self) - 15, elementHeight(self))];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(elementWidth(self), 0)];
                [_path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(15, 0)];
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
        mask.frame = self.bounds;
        mask.path = _path.CGPath;

        self.layer.mask = mask;

    }

    return self;
}
```

**Allow touch events inside of the shape only**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    if ([_path containsPoint:touchLocation]) {
        NSLog(@"Inside!");
        [super sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Outside!");
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    if ([_path containsPoint:touchLocation]) {
        NSLog(@"Ended Inside!");
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Ended Outside!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By getting around the documentation, I found out that there is a property called **highlighted**
So I just added `self.highligthed = YES;` on touchesBegan and `self.highligthed = NO;` on touchesCancelled and touchesEnded.

Hope this helps someone in the future.